# What are the R - families of connections

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, principal-bundles

I've the definition of a connection on a vector bundle and on a G-principal bundle. But reading I have found this statement

> if R is a $\mathbb{C}-$algebra take the R-families of connections over the formal disk

Where the formal disk is $Spec\mathbb{C}[[t]]$
What they mean? There is another classical definitions that I've lost?

Comment: You need to link to your sources. None of this is remotely standard enough for someone to answer without knowing your particular context.

Comment: There are linked several facts that can help to understand it. The first is that  exists a notion of equivalence between connections but I don't know what is and the second is that on a formal disk the G-principal bundle are trivial for "good" G.

Comment: I'm sorry? Let me rephrase: what book/notes are you getting all of your definitions from in the first place?